# FlowType não esta atualizando quando maximiza/restaura janela

Tags: javascript, jquery

O Flowtype não esta atualizando o tamanho correto da fonte quando eu carrego a página sem a janela estar maximizada e maximizo ela. Quando a janela é maximizada a fonte aparece no tamanho que deveria estar quando não estava maximizada. E se eu restaurar para não ficar maximizado a fonte fica com o tamanho que devia estar quando maximizada. Se eu redimensionar a janela com o mouse nas bordas o Flowtype funciona bem. Isso seria um bug ou eu estou fazendo algo errado no JavaScript? Eu estou chamando o Flowtype quando a página é carregada, se eu mover o codigo para quando a janela é redimensionada o Flowtype não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o bug foi removido na versão 1.1. Atualize a versão.

### Edit:

Agora não sei se a versão 1.1 corrige mesmo ou não. Mas consegui eliminar o problema chamando o FlowType com as mesmas opções no evento onload e no evento resize.

Comment: De qual fonte você tirou essa informação?

Comment: Simplesmente ví que havia uma versão mais nova, e testei. No meu teste não tem mais o bug. https://github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS

Comment: Estranho, as vezes da o problema e as vezes não. Se eu chamar o flowtype nos eventos onload e onresize funciona tranquilo.